# How can I convert strings to list, without using the split fuction

Tags: python

I am going to convert:
sample_date = "23-05-2000"
into a list, with while loop.

example:

```
"23-05-2000" -> [23, 05, 2000]
```

Comment: why without `split()`?

Comment: To save yourself from some future trouble, you should look into the `datetime` modules before reinventing the wheel if you're heading that direction

Comment: This seems like a really basic thing, and so there are many ways to go about this. Why do you need to do this without `split()`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This task requires that I convert it to a list without using the split method

Comment: Hello @sigurdhovet, 
What you want to do ? With python we had multiple way's to do.

Comment: This kind of assigment is a non-sense .. Learn python without using the python methods. And if the assigment is about learning while lopp or just algorithm there dozens of othre example

Comment: It's my first year of studing engieering, so we have not learned so many ways to code. The task would be easy if I could use split, but we are going to learn how to use while loops :)

Comment: Perhaps their instructor is trying force an understanding basic programming: In python, it is possible to get by without understanding certain nuts and bolts stuff, material that you would absolutely have to grasp if your first programming language was C :) That said, @azro is totally correct, there are many more useful ways to teach this than the example under discussion

Comment: is it to integer list or str list?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = "23-05-2000"

y = re.sub("-", ", ", s)

z = [] 

z.append(y)

print(z)
```

output

```
['23, 05, 2000']
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder if the OP's instructor, who banned the use of  ```string.split()```, would let his students use ```re```...?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code using while loop

```
count = 0
a = "23-05-2000"
e = []
c = ""
while(count != len(a)):
    if a[count]=="-":
         e.append(int(c))
         c = ""
    else:
         c += a[count]
    count+=1
 e.append(int(c))
 #e will have the output you want
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module for this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "23-05-2000"
date_format = "%d-%m-%Y" # zero-padded day, zero-padded month, year with century

dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
dt_list = [dt.day, dt.month, dt.year]

print(dt_list)
```

```
[23, 5, 2000]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a while loop

```
sample_date = "23-05-2000"
part = ''
l = []
while sample_date:
    head = sample_date[0]
    sample_date = sample_date[1:]
    if head == '-':      
        l.append(int(part))
        part = ''
    else:
        part += head
l.append(int(part))

print(l)
```

Output

```
[23, 5, 2000]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `partition()` to do something with each token of the input:

```
input = '23-05-2000'
output = []
while input:
   token, _, input = input.partition('-')
   do_something_with(token)
   output.append(int(token))

# assert(output == [23, 5, 2000])
```

Answer (score 1):

because we cant use **.split()**, we had a few approaches.

### How to split a *string* without using the *.split()*

```
### using a while ###

# Creating variables

input_string = "10-20-30-40-50"
split_character = '-'

run = True
result = []
memory = ''
index = 0
string_size = len(input_string) # here we will discovery the size of the string

### The While cycle
# 1º try - we will run all characters of the string
while run:

    # First we'll check if we archive the end do the index
    if string_size <= index:
        run = False
        result.append(int(memory))
        break


    # Verify if the character on that index is the split_character
    # If True : will add on memory the input_string[index]
    if input_string[index] != split_character:
        memory = memory + input_string[index]

    # if the input_string[index] is equals to the split_character, the variable memory will be append to result and reset memory to ''
    else:
        result.append(int(memory))
        memory = ''

    index = index + 1

print(result)
```

You also can use the 'for' to do. Will be much simple also clear.
If you had any doubts, just ask.